# ggplot2 freqpoly: why do the values on x-axis go negative?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot frequency polygon for `diamonds` data set as :

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, colour=color)) +
      geom_freqpoly(binwidth=100)
```

The output from the above call is:

[image]

I cannot understand this plot. Why are the values of `carat` in the negative x-axis?

The following statement:

```
unique(diamonds$carat > 0)
```

results in `TRUE`. Then why does it plot `carat` with negative values?

Also, how do we exactly read this graph? This is not a regular histogram.

Comment: It's not the data, it's the way you plot it. You use [`geom_freqpoly`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html) which "divides the x axis into bins and counts the number of observations in each bin"; "more suitable when you want to compare the distribution across a the levels of a categorical variable." Try visualizing your data using `geom_line`

Comment: The issue is your `binwidth`

Comment: It's probably a combination of the very wide binwidth, relative to the data (carat ranges from 0.2 to 5), and how `geom_freqpoly` chooses where to set the bin boundaries. Try, for example: `ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, colour=color)) +
      geom_freqpoly(binwidth=0.2)`

Comment: Running this code might also be helpful: `ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, colour=color)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth=100)`;
`ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, colour=color)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth=100, boundary=0)`;
`ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, colour=color)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5)`;
`ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, colour=color)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, boundary=0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the binwidth or remove the parameter.

Here is a demonstration of similar problem:

[image: inverted v with negative x-axis value]

The shape changes with smaller binwidth and the negative range ceased:

[image: binwidth=100]

[image: binwidth=10]

You can also omit the bandwidth parameter:

[image: no bindwidth]